# Logout user when user permission changes in active directory when user is logged in from ADFS SSO

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs

I have an application that authenticates from ADFS 2016 using openidConnect. 
Once I get token form ADFS I create local cookie session in my application.

Problem 
When permission for user changes on ADFS server or user is disabled, how my application can trigger logout for user. ADFS provides any endpoint or api to check that?

Comment: was the answer below useful?

Answer (score 1):

Access token you get from AD FS has a certain lifetime (configurable on AD FS side). The default value is one hour. You can read more about AD FS token lifetime [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

With AD FS you do not have any "built into the protocol" way to logout the user from your application exactly at the time when you disable it in AD, but you can set expiration time for the cookies in your application, so when the cookies expire, the application will go and try to get a new access token or refresh an existing token depending on your needs and arhitecture.

**Option #1**: **Get new access token**

If the user was disabled he will not be able to get a new access token and will not be able to login into your application. If the the user was still active by the time when a local cookie in your application expired, the AD FS login process will be seamless for him. I.e. he will not even see the AD FS login page and will be redirected back to your application with a new access token right  away.

**Option #2**: **Refresh existing access token**

This option is only available when you persist AD FS access tokens in your application. You can use a certain endpoint at AD FS server to try to refresh that access token. If a used was disable he will not be able to refresh the token and you can perform a logout. You can read more about how to refresh the access token and some other scenarios with AD FS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-scenarios-for-developers).